# Python3: trying to insert text between two characters - inputFile is conflicting with file.write()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a PHP associative array to file.

```
return [
    'welcome' => 'Welcome to our application'
];
```

- If the file doesn't exist, I write the array above to the file
- If the file already exists, I add a comma to the string inside the array, then I remove `];` then I add the second row then I close the array.
- All the individual code snippets are working, when I put them together, I start having problems, kinda like a race condition.

The code

```
import fileinput
from pathlib import Path
import os

def translateLaravel(filename, expression):
    key = "".join([expression[0], filename, "__", expression[1:]])
    key = key.replace(" ", "_")
    key = key.strip('')
    translation_file_path = 'files/Translation.php'

    if os.path.isfile(translation_file_path) == False: # the file doesn't exist
        string = "".join(['<?php', '\n', 'return [', '\n', key, ' => ', expression, '\n', '];'])
        with open(translation_file_path, 'w') as the_file:
            the_file.write(string)
    else:
        with fileinput.FileInput(os.path.abspath(translation_file_path), inplace=True) as file:
            for line in file:
                if '=>' in line:
                    line = line.rstrip()
                    if not line.endswith(','):
                        print(line.replace(line, ''.join([line, ',', '\n'])))

                elif '];' in line:
                    print(line.replace(line,''))


        with open(translation_file_path, 'a') as the_file:
            the_file.write(''.join([key, ' => ', expression, '\n', '];']))            
    return key
```

What's happening:

- `if os.path.isfile(translation_file_path)` returns false and the code
  executes, but it doesn't write anything to the file
- If I remove the else condition, then the former starts working again without any problem.

Therefore I suspect that file.write() is not having enough time to write to the file, but apparently I'm wrong because I tried `sleep(1)` in order to give `file.write()` enough time, that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Why don't you use JSON format for the file instead of creating a PHP source file?

Comment: You don't need to remove the last comma. PHP allows you to have a trailing comma in an array.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the tip in the second comment :) as for the first comment, because my company uses [laravel localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/localization) which uses php

Comment: Why are you using both `fileinput` with the `inplace` option and also appending to the same file? Just add the new line while reading and rewriting the input file.

Comment: `print(line.replace(line,''))` isn't that the same as just `print('')`?

Comment: **I suspect that file.write() is not having enough time to write to the file** File I/O is synchronous unless you use the `asyncio` module.

Comment: Are you saying that the behavior of the code in the `if` block depends on whether there's an `else` block, even though the `if` condition is true? That's not possible.

Comment: Don't you need to add quotes around the key and expression?

Comment: In general, `print(line.replace(line, anything))` is the same as `print(anything)`.

Comment: @Barmar yes I need to add quotes around the key, I don't need to add it around the expression because I'm extracting it as a string from php files, so it's already quoted. I'll try your suggestions. And regarding the if behaviour, that's true, if you remove the else, then if would write to a file.

Comment: You're probably wrong about which branch is being taken. Add some `print` statements that tell you which branch is executing.